# FullTextSearch in MYSql

Tags: java, mysql

In mysql fulltext search, the match gives some values,I don't know which one is mentioned by that values?
I need the comparsion output in percentage?How can i achieve that?

```
SELECT id,title,body,MATCH (title,body)
 AGAINST ('database') FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
 AGAINST ('database');
```

Output:

```
id',   'title',                    'body',                     'MATCH'
1, 'MYSql Tutorial', 'My Sql is one of the database language', 0.93769526481628
10, 'MySQL vs. YourSQL', 'In the following database comparison ...', 0.93769526481628
6, 'MySQL Tutorial', 'DBMS stands for DataBase ...', 0.92749810218811
```

Comment: You want to get match percent for title and body separeted ?

Comment: Ya.Its appreciable.One more doubt,can you explain about my output compare with my query?I am little confused with that.

Comment: It seems it doesnt match with your `title` column, and almost all body  column have 'database' string in it so its matching with high percent

Comment: "almost all body column have 'database' string in it so its matching with high percent",i can't understand your quotes.Can you please elaborate?Becasue the match is different for 1 and 3?why its different?And how the match is like 0.937695.. and 0.92749810218811?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want the relevance as well as the result. That would look something like:

```
SELECT id, title, body, MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('database') as Relevance FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('database' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `Relevance` DESC
```

**edit** I got the question wrong. Here's a list of all relevance's in percentage form:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.body, 
MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('database') as titleRelevance, 
MATCH(a.body) AGAINST ('database') as bodyRelevance,
MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('database')/c.maxTitleRelevance *100 AS percentageTitleRelevance,
MATCH(a.body) AGAINST ('database')/d.maxBodyRelevance *100 AS percentageBodyRelevance,
c.maxTitleRelevance + d.maxBodyRelevance AS maxTotalRelevance,
(MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('database')+MATCH(a.body) AGAINST ('database'))/(c.maxTitleRelevance + d.maxBodyRelevance)*100 AS percentageTotalRelevance
FROM `articles` a, 
(SELECT MAX(MATCH(b.title) AGAINST('database')) as maxTitleRelevance FROM articles b LIMIT 1) c,
(SELECT MAX(MATCH(b.body) AGAINST('database')) as maxBodyRelevance FROM articles b LIMIT 1) d
WHERE MATCH(a.title, a.body) AGAINST ('database' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This might be easier to read in the following fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7885/14
Full text searches in mysql are flaky at best. If the word database is in at least 50% of rows of the db, it will be ignored as a common stopword if you dont specify boolean mode like in the query above. In terms of how relevance is calculated I'm afraid I cant help you there.